# How to Prevent ViewModel from destroying

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I am building an app to save the user details step by step with multiple fragments. I used multiple fragments which shares same view model. But when i am navigating from last fragment to previous fragment ( to edit details that already provided ) the shared ViewModel destroys. Is there any way to prevent it from destroying ?!

Comment: "But when i am navigating from last fragment to previous fragment ( to edit details that already provided ) the shared ViewModel destroys" -- if you are using an activity-scoped `ViewModel`, and these fragments are in the same activity, the `ViewModel` should not get cleared. You might consider a [mcve] to show how you have things set up and how you are determining that your `ViewModel` is getting cleared.

Comment: The only time the ViewModel gets destroyed is when the context(usually activity) that was used to create it is also destroyed. If you are sending your ViewModel reference to your fragment via fragmet.viewModel = viewModel from the activity. Then it might be the problem, because you shouldn't be doing it like that.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code snippet where this issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using multiple fragments inside a single activity, make use you are providing the ViewModels using the activity context instead of the fragment context.

In your fragments, it should be like this:

```
vm = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!, vmFactory)[vmclass.java]
```